# Date format expression in BASH when adding days

Tags: bash, date

So I am writing a date calculation Bash and I am having issues with date format. Maybe I am just writing it wrong, any insite is helpful

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "bill date"
read date

      d1=$(date -d  "$date +27 days")
      d2=$(date -d  "$date +45 days" )


echo "$(tput bold setaf 3)Suspension date = $d1" 
echo "$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)Termination date = $d2"
```

What I would like is the output to be: Suspension date = Mon Nov 6 2017

what I get is Suspension date = Mon Nov  6 00:00:00 EST 2017

I have tried many variations of and placements of +'%a %B %d %Y' and I keep getting invalid date errors.

hitting my head against my desk and wall have not knocked anything loose so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use a date format string:

```
d1="$(date -d "$date +27 days" +"%a %b %d %Y")"
```

This depends entirely upon the user inputting a format that is parseable by `date -d`.

Comment: I appeared to have been missing the outside " " and that is what was breaking everything, Thank you!